# Is it ok to ask since when a particular teaching/doctrine was known?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'd like to ask the question since when the doctrine of the *rapture* was known (or rediscovered). But I feel that this is not technically a hermeneutic question. So, is it possible to ask this question on biblical hermeneutics. If not, could I change the question somehow that it fits the target questions of biblical hermeneutics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions about the history of a doctrine in Christianity such as when a particular viewpoint came on the scene or came to prominence are probably better suited to [Christianity.SE](http://christianity.stackexchange.com). Even though the question involves hermeneutics, it's not specifically about a passage and how to interpret it so much as how a specific subset of Christians have interpreted it. That makes it inherently off topic here but quite well suited for C.SE.

What you describe is essentially a variant of what we've come to call "Biblical basis" questions, by which the C.SE community means questions about the perceived Scriptural support for any given doctrine (whether right or wrong). What your looking for is the history of how various scriptures have been interpreted as they relate to a specific doctrine.

Comment: I think it would be more of an history or origin question.