# What are the main differences and main similarities between Biblical Hermeneutics site and Christianity site?

Tags: discussion

The title is the question, I could ask it in the body of the question but there is no need to repeat myself. I would also like to be aware what questions are exactly for one and what are for the other site, if there is some pretty clear distinction.

Answer (score 3):

This has been rehashed a hundred different ways. Please at least browse through some of the previous discussions.

For starters there is the very first question ever asked on this site:

- [How can this site distinguish itself from Christianity.SE?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/36)

Then there are a plethora of questions in the [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) tag that relate to this issue:

- [Friends, we are not Christian!](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/441/36)
- [How can this site distinguish itself from Christianity.SE?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/36)
- [All traditions are welcome on Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/892/36)
- [Hermeneutics vs Exegesis](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15/36)
- [Site Viability and the Distinction Between Scriptural and Biblical Studies](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/671/36)
- [What texts are open for examination?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4/36)
- [Topicality of a Textual Question related to a Group with a Specific Doctrinal Commitment](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3264/36)
- [Are questions about historic interpretations on-topic?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26/36)
- [Why should one participate in the Biblical Hermeneutics site (is it a viable site)?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/466/36)
- [Is it ok to ask since when a particular teaching/doctrine was known?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3211/36)
- [Questions asking for bible reference/Bible translation](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3168/36)
- [What constitutes doctrine?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/428/36)
- [Exactly what types of questions is the Biblical Hermeneutics site intended to answer?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/188/36)
- [What kind of site do we ultimately want to have?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/735/36)

Then there are a plethora of questions on the C.SE meta site talking about this from the other side of the fence.

- https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/193/30
- https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5911/30
- https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/784/30
- https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1506/30
- https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1783/30
- https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/690/30

These are only a sampler. If you have some specific genre of question in mind both meta sites likely have some discussion about how to handle them best. In short, if you want to learn about the *process* of interpreting the Bible, ask on BH.SE. If you want to learn about how Christians *have* interpreted the Bible, ask on C.SE.